# Checking if character matches List of Acceptable characters

Tags: java, regex

I'm writing a program that does delimiter checking. When the user inputs an expression such as

```
12+{2*[3*(24+45)+5]}
```

I need to check whether the delimiters match (kind of like what the java compiler checks for in our expressions).

I know this can be done with a ton of `if`/`else if` statements, but I remember using regex for strings, ex:

```
if(s.matches("[abc]+")
System.out.print(s);
```

But that doesn't work for characters. It would be nice if I could write an expression similar to the one above:

```
for(byte i = 0; i < aString.length(); i++)
{
    if(aString.charAt(i).matches("[({[]})]+")   // maybe '[]' is a problem
    stack.push(aString.charAt(i));
}
```

Does such a method exist for characters? What can I do?

Comment: I think regex for this is the wrong way to go. It could get mighty ugly. For example, how would you handle `"[3 + (2 * 4])"`?

Comment: I just need to know if the specific characters is one of the ones acceptable. If it is then - using another algorithm - I will check to see if it matches the previous one; if it doesn't, an exception will be thrown. So this checking process would skip letters, numbers, arithmetic operators, etc.

Comment: Ah so this algorithm would not care about delimiter ordering either?

Comment: It will check if the first matches the last, the second matches the second to last - you know, similar to what your scientific calculator checks for before it gives you that (syntax error!). So since ( and ] doesn't match, it would throw an error. Thanks!

Comment: `"[{()}}".indexOf(theChar) <= 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say one solution to this would be using a [Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) and start over at each input string.

1. When a open bracket `{, [, (` is found, **push** it onto the stack.
2. When a close bracket `}, ], )` is found, **pop** it from the stack.
3. Compare using an if statement seeing if you have a match. Return `false` if you do not.

When you finish with your search, check if you have an empty stack and either return `true` or `false`

[Stack Example: Delimiter Matching](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/StackExampleDelimiterMatching.htm)

This example of using Stack will only return `false` if you are missing a delimiter match.

```
import java.util.Stack;

class BracketChecker {
  private String input;

  public BracketChecker(String in) {
    input = in;
  }

  public void check() {
    Stack<Character> theStack = new Stack<Character>();

    for (int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++) {
      char ch = input.charAt(j);
      switch (ch) {
      case '{': 
      case '[':
      case '(':
        theStack.push(ch);
        break;
      case '}': 
      case ']':
      case ')':
        if (!theStack.isEmpty()) {
          char chx = theStack.pop();
          if ((ch == '}' && chx != '{') || 
              (ch == ']' && chx != '[') || 
              (ch == ')' && chx != '('))
              System.out.println("Error: " + ch + " at " + j);
          } else
              System.out.println("Error: " + ch + " at " + j);
              break;
              default:
              break;
          }
    }
    if (!theStack.isEmpty()){
      System.out.println("Error: missing right delimiter");
    }
  }
}

class delimTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input = "12+{2*[3*(24+45)+5}";

    BracketChecker theChecker = new BracketChecker(input);
    theChecker.check();
  }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what my program does, pushes an opening delimiter when it's encountered, and pops it when it's counter part is encountered. My dilemma is how to identify them as efficiently as possible. It seems that you have some experience with this, hopefully you know a way. Either way, thanks! (:

Comment: This is no dissimilar to what I was doing, but the way that you implemented it is exceptional. I didn't know java had a built-in stack structure, now I know. Thanks for the example. (:

Answer (score 2):

You can maintain a `List<Character>` that holds "delimiter" characters, then run  `list.contains()` on every character in the string to determine whether it's a valid delimiter - that'd be a lot more performant than regexes for your task. You might want to rethink looping over a `String` using a `byte` as your loop variable, though; that might not always work out well for you. For a simple string (no fancy Unicode characters beyond the BMP), you could loop over it using `for (char ch : aString.toCharArray()) {...}`.

Comment: That sounds as if it could work, unfortunately I don't know how to implement lists yet. So this is kind of beyond my capabilities. As for the byte, I think it will suffice since I will enforce a maximum length of 100 characters. Let me know if there are some other consequences I may be overlooking. Thanks! (:

Comment: In that case, I'd probably recommend writing a separate method that takes a character as input and returns a boolean representing whether or not the input char is a delimiter. Just run that on every character in your loop instead of cluttering your loop with a bunch of if/elses. (Hint: think about how you could use the || operator to implement `isDelimiter()`).

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that option, I was hoping for a java language feature that would let me circumvent that alternative. Oh well, I guess I can't expect an easy way for everything. Thanks!

Comment: No problem :). Actually, I think the easiest way would be the List route - even if you could use regexes on characters (and btw, you _could_ make a new String out of each character as you're looping if you really wanted to use regexes...but please don't), you wouldn't want to because it would be very inefficient for what you're doing. Since you're not familiar with Lists, though, I don't think this utility method will be all that bad to code.